# Generating an html file for use in iframe

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I'm using [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to generate `frame.html` that will be used in an iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="/frame.html" ... />
```

However, when I run `gatsby develop`, I get:

> ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
>
> Generating SSR bundle failed
>
> Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename render-page.js (chunks frame and main)

Repro is here: [moroshko/gatsby-iframe-issue](https://github.com/moroshko/gatsby-iframe-issue)

See [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19872) for more context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During SSR Gatsby enforces webpack's output config to `render-page.js` and this affects your custom entry `frame` too, resulting in the conflict error.

To get past this, you should check if `onCreateWebpackConfig` is in SSR stage and bail if this is the case.

```js
const path = require("path")
const merge = require("webpack-merge")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, getConfig, stage }) => {
  if ( stage.endsWith('-html') ) {
    return
  }

  let modifiedConfig = getConfig()

  modifiedConfig = merge(modifiedConfig, {
    entry: {
      frame: path.resolve("./src/frame.js"),
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: "Component Preview",
        chunks: ["frame"],
        filename: "frame.html",
      }),
    ],
  })

  actions.replaceWebpackConfig(modifiedConfig)
}
```